# How to monitor APK files in Android System

Tags: tools, android, apk

Is there a monitoring tool for Android except `logcat` which works like Process Monitor in Windows ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have root access in device you can use [ps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_%28Unix%29), also you can use [/proc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) file system.

Answer (score 2):

I have used "File Monitor" from SteelWorks (I am not associated with this company in any way) on a non-routed Android device and it works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this app doesn't show operations (read/write etc.) completed on assets files in Android apps, so it's useless for reverse engineering such apps.